# Nuxt how to make div take up entire screen until user scrolls down

Tags: nuxt.js, css-animations

I have this div with a class of `hero`:

```html
        <div class="hero" >
            <img src="/logo.png" alt="1x1 Photos logo" class="logo backlit">
            <h1 class="backlit text-8xl">1x1 Photos</h1>
            <button class="btn inverse">2024 Calendars for Sale</button>
        </div>
```

When the page first loads, I want `hero` to be full screen. Once the user starts scrolling, how can I make it shrink, then disappear (with the exception of the `button` and `img`, those should be small and in a row) to show the `main` content?